# deleting Child and Parent Entities on Spring MVC makes ConstraintViolationException

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have 2 JPA Entities in a Spring MVC Server. One of them is the "parent" and other is the Child.
As I read [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-dataIntegrityviolationexception) (Cause 4)that when I have an parent and child Entities, firstly a have to delete the parent and after delete the child. It is making a org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException

Parent Entity **Project**

> ```
> @Entity
> public class Project {  
> @Id
> @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
> @JsonIgnore
> private long id;
> private String project_name;
> private Date date;
> private String nome_classe;
> @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
> List<respostas> Listarespostas = new ArrayList<respostas>(); //CHILD !!!!
> public Project()
> {}
> //gets and sets
> }
> ```

Child Entity **Respostas**

> ```
> @Entity
> public class respostas {
> @Id
> @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
> @JsonIgnore
> private long id;
> @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
> List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
> String respostasjson;
> public respostas()
> {}
> public respostas(List<String> lista)
> {
>     this.lista = lista;
>     Gson gson = new Gson();
>     gson.toJson(lista);
> }
> public void addResposta(String resposta)
> {
>     lista.add(resposta);
> }
> public void removeResposta(int i)
> {
>     lista.remove(i);
> }
> public String getRespostasjson() {
>     return respostasjson;
> }
> public void setRespostasjson(String respostasjson) {
>     this.respostasjson = respostasjson;
> }
> public List<String> getLista() {
>     return lista;
> }
> }
> ```

I try to delete them in a "@RequestMapping(value = "delete")" in my **Controller**

> ```
>  @RequestMapping(value = "delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
> public ModelAndView DeletePostoSaude(Principal p,HttpServletResponse response) 
> {
>     if(p.getName().equals("coursera"))
>     {
>         Projects.deleteAll();
>         respostas.deleteAll();
>     }
> }
> ```

But the **ConstraintViolationException** still appears:

> Hibernate: select project0_.id as id1_5_, project0_.date as date2_5_, project0_.listaperguntasjson as listaper3_5_, project0_.listarespostasjson as listares4_5_, project0_.nome_classe as nome_cla5_5_, project0_.project_name as project_6_5_ from Project project0_
>   Hibernate: delete from Project_Listaperguntas where Project_id=?
>   Hibernate: delete from Project where id=?
>   2014-11-18 10:29:26.599  WARN 980 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23503, SQLState: 23503
>   2014-11-18 10:29:26.599 ERROR 980 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Violación de una restricción de Integridad Referencial: "FK_547Q6QW5LUAR2Q292SPD53J5G: PUBLIC.PROJECT_LISTARESPOSTAS FOREIGN KEY(PROJECT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PROJECT(ID) (193)"
>   Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_547Q6QW5LUAR2Q292SPD53J5G: PUBLIC.PROJECT_LISTARESPOSTAS FOREIGN KEY(PROJECT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PROJECT(ID) (193)"; SQL statement:
>   delete from Project where id=? [23503-175]
>   2014-11-18 10:29:26.599  INFO 980 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
>   2014-11-18 10:29:26.601 ERROR 980 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FK_547Q6QW5LUAR2Q292SPD53J5G: PUBLIC.PROJECT_LISTARESPOSTAS FOREIGN KEY(PROJECT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PROJECT(ID) (193)"; SQL statement:
>   delete from Project where id=? [23503-175]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Violación de una restricción de Integridad Referencial: "FK_547Q6QW5LUAR2Q292SPD53J5G: PUBLIC.PROJECT_LISTARESPOSTAS FOREIGN KEY(PROJECT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PROJECT(ID) (193)"
>   Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_547Q6QW5LUAR2Q292SPD53J5G: PUBLIC.PROJECT_LISTARESPOSTAS FOREIGN KEY(PROJECT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PROJECT(ID) (193)"; SQL statement:
>   delete from Project where id=? [23503-175]

Any solution? (Each entity has its CrudRepository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error it seems your tables work the other way around. I see a PROJECT_LISTARESPOSTAS referencing the PROJECT. Try deleting with opposite order:

```
respostas.deleteAll();
Projects.deleteAll();
```

you may also want to check the delete cascade option so that when deleting an entity, reference entities are deleted too. That could be as simple as putting an annotation `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` on the column that references the other table (check the spring jpa documentation for more info)

Comment: I tried serveral tentatives and all of them gives the same error (above error, in the question), including the deleting order you suggested. If I put the `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` on the `@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
List<respostas> Listarespostas = new ArrayList<respostas>();` (Child) the below error appears.I tried to put in the top of the 'respostas entity(the child, and it doesn't correct anything)'. > aused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: only inverse one-to-many associations may use on-delete="cascade": palmaslab.mapas.repository.Project.Listarespostas

Comment: The problem was that i created this `ListaRespostas` with another ID. The solution was to delete the database and put the your deleting order in my code. Thank you